# How to fix " Property 'wheelDelta' does not exist on type 'WheelEvent' " while upgrading to angular 7,rxjs6?

Tags: angular7, rxjs6

I'm upgrading to angular7 with rxjs6: in `mouseWheelEvent` type I am getting `"Property 'wheelDelta' does not exist on type 'WheelEvent'"`.

Do we have any alternative for `wheelDelta`?

```
mouseWheelFunc(event: MouseWheelEvent): void {

    //  var event = window.event || event; // old IE support

    let delta = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, (event.wheelDelta || -event.detail)));

    if ( delta > 0) {
      this.mouseWheelUp.emit(event);
    } else if ( delta < 0) {
      this.mouseWheelDown.emit(event);
    }

    // for IE
    event.returnValue = false;
    // for Chrome and Firefox
    if ( event.preventDefault) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }
```

> ERROR in
>   src/modules/components/numeric-stepper/mousewheel.directive.ts(23,49):
>   error TS2339: Property 'wheelDelta' does not exist on type
>   'WheelEvent'.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems like WheelEvent doesn't have this property anymore as it says. Now they added deltaY and deltaX.

Now you have to access `event.deltaY` instead of `event.wheelData`.

But deltaY has the opposite value of wheelData. That means when wheelData on the event was positive (scroll up) deltaY will be a negative number, and vice versa.

**Example:**

Change this:

```
        zoomScroll(event: WheelEvent) {
            if (event.wheelDelta > 0) {
                this.zoomIn();
            } else if (event.wheelDelta < 0) {
                this.zoomOut();
            }
        }
```

For this:

```
       zoomScroll(event: WheelEvent) {
           if (event.deltaY < 0) {
               this.zoomIn();
           } else if (event.deltaY > 0) {
               this.zoomOut();
           }
    }
```

source: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9071

Comment: Thank you for this!