# view document that exists on the server

Tags: angular

I want to view a file with in the html page that exists on the server.
I'm using angular  8.0.0 version.
I have tried ngx-file-viewer.
But it got an error called "Property 'wheelDelta' does not exist on type 'WheelEvent' ".

I have tried to solve that using event.deltaY instead of using event.wheelData which marked for the solution within the "[How to fix " Property 'wheelDelta' does not exist on type 'WheelEvent' " while upgrading to angular 7,rxjs6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54258968/how-to-fix-property-wheeldelta-does-not-exist-on-type-wheelevent-while-u)".

But after that it gets an error called " Cannot find name 'module'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i @types/node` and then add `node` to the types field in your tsconfig.".

can anyone tell me how to solve that?

After edit the code

```
         @HostListener('wheel', ['$event'])
           onWheel(event:MouseWheelEvent) {
           this.changeZoom(event.deltaY/2400);
           return false;
         }
```

Comment: Did you get the file from your server first? What type of file is it?

Comment: yeah. It can be docx or pdf file.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-file-viewer It doesns't support docx.

Comment: In the case of PDF files, there are several solutions: `<ngx-extended-pdf-viewer>`, ng2-pdfjs-viewer, and ng2-pdf-viewer, just to name a few. Have a look at my showcase. Currently, it's concentrating on my own library (ngx-extended-pdf-viewer), but it mentions the alternatives, and it'll cover them in much more detail soon: https://www.pdfviewer.net/simple

Answer (score 0):

Extending my comment, for pdfs you could use the accepted answer from this question: [[Recommended way to embed PDF in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291813/recommended-way-to-embed-pdf-in-html][1]).
I haven't used ngx-file-viewer but it is an experimental plugin. I wouldn't use it on production or frequently update code.

Comment: Is there any module to use for view any type of document  files?

Comment: Every answer I searched is by uploading the said files in google docs or officeapps and then loading them from there. Check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27957766/how-do-i-render-a-word-document-doc-docx-in-the-browser-using-javascript

Comment: I refer that. But it gets an error "Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist."