# How do I transition background color with Tailwind CSS in React?

Tags: css, reactjs, css-transitions, gatsby, tailwind-css

I am building a gatsby site and I want to have my header change background color opacity as I scroll down. What's the best way to approach this?

I currently have this, where isScrolled is a state value that I'm updating with a custom hook. The problem I have is that there is no transition appearing, I'm pretty sure because React is re-rendering the whole component when the state changes.

What would be the appropriate tool / method for solving this problem?

```
 <header
          className={
            `h-16 z-10 fixed top-0 left-0 w-screen transition-all`
              ${
               isScrolled ? "bg-white" : "bg-transparent"
             }`
          }
        >
          <div className="px-8 container mx-auto flex items-center justify-between h-full">
            <Logo />
            <nav>
              <HeaderLink to="about-us">About</HeaderLink>
              <HeaderLink to="blog">Blog</HeaderLink>
              <HeaderLink to="contact">Contact</HeaderLink>
            </nav>
          </div>
        </header>
```

I've tried the HeadlessUI Transition component but that doesn't work because it only transitions in an entire component (as opposed to a property) and I haven't been able to get React-Transition-Group working either. Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try use this in your component,

```
...
const [isScrolled, setIsScrolled] = useState(false);
...
  <header
    className={`h-16 z-10 fixed top-0 left-0 w-screen transition-all duration-200
          ${isScrolled ? "bg-white" : "bg-transparent"}`}
  >
```

and read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62497110/detect-scroll-direction-in-react-js) to detect the correct scroll event.
Happy coding!

***Update version in Dec. 2023*** is useing `clsx` package

Install clsx package [check this package document](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clsx)

```
import clsx from 'clsx'
...
// state define to use conditional logic
const [isScrolled, setIsScrolled] = useState(false);
...
// define base css classes as constant
const base = 'h-16 z-10 fixed top-0 left-0 w-screen transition-all duration-200' as string

return (
   ...
     <header className={clsx(base, isScrolled ? "bg-white" : "bg-transparent")}
  >
   ...
)
```

Another usages

```
// Strings (variadic)
clsx('foo', true && 'bar', 'baz');
//=> 'foo bar baz'

// Objects
clsx({ foo:true, bar:false, baz:isTrue() });
//=> 'foo baz'

// Objects (variadic)
clsx({ foo:true }, { bar:false }, null, { '--foobar':'hello' });
//=> 'foo --foobar'

// Arrays
clsx(['foo', 0, false, 'bar']);
//=> 'foo bar'

// Arrays (variadic)
clsx(['foo'], ['', 0, false, 'bar'], [['baz', [['hello'], 'there']]]);
//=> 'foo bar baz hello there'

// Kitchen sink (with nesting)
clsx('foo', [1 && 'bar', { baz:false, bat:null }, ['hello', ['world']]], 'cya');
//=> 'foo bar hello world cya'
```

Happy coding :)

Comment: This is applying transition for everything not only background-color !

Comment: Well you can change `transition-all` to `transition-colors`